# SSAS excel remote connection

Tags: excel, ssas, sql-server-2014, iis-8.5

I migrated to SQL Server 2014 from 2008 version. I have Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5.

I'm trying to configure remote access to my OLAP database . I followed all the steps as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/gg492140(v=sql.120).aspx.

The IIS version mentioned is the 8.0, does it fit for the 8.5 too?

When I try to test the configuration using the Management Studio I get this error:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The connection either timed out or was lost. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

---

The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. (System)

---

```
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Discover(String requestType, String requestNamespace, ListDictionary properties, IDictionary restrictions, Boolean sendNamespacesCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SupportsProperty(String propName)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectXmla()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. (System)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseStream()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseDataType()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can I do to get more details in order to find what goes wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!